# unmet dependencies when using apt-get, how can I solve it?

Tags: apt

When I try to install packages I get this error, what is wrong and how can I fix it?

```
dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `libisccc60' faltando,
assumindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `libsepol1' faltando, a
ssumindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `libxapian15' faltando,
 assumindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `ntfs-3g' faltando, ass
umindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `whiptail' faltando, as
sumindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `libdrm2' faltando, ass
umindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `libmagic1' faltando, a
ssumindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `netbase' faltando, ass
umindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `bc' faltando, assumind
o que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `libk5crypto3' faltando
, assumindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `mtr-tiny' faltando, as
sumindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `libgc1c2' faltando, as
sumindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `grub-common' faltando,
 assumindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `ubuntu-standard' falta
ndo, assumindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `libdbus-glib-1-2' falt
ando, assumindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `pciutils' faltando, as
sumindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `sgml-base' faltando, a
ssumindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `libisc60' faltando, as
sumindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `apt' faltando, assumin
do que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `libtimedate-perl' falt
ando, assumindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `sysv-rc' faltando, ass
umindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `perl-base' faltando, a
ssumindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `ncurses-bin' faltando,
 assumindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `byobu' faltando, assum
indo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `lvm2' faltando, assumi
ndo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `python-gnupginterface'
 faltando, assumindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `openssl' faltando, ass
umindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `vim-common' faltando,
assumindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `bzip2' faltando, assum
indo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `libssl0.9.8' faltando,
 assumindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `ssl-cert' faltando, as
sumindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `update-inetd' faltando
, assumindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `lsb-release' faltando,
 assumindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `apport-symptoms' falta
ndo, assumindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `install-info' faltando
, assumindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.
(Lendo banco de dados ... 30%
dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `sensible-utils' faltan
do, assumindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `bsdutils' faltando, as
sumindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `perl-modules' faltando
, assumindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `ucf' faltando, assumin
do que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `psmisc' faltando, assu
mindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `libgpg-error0' faltand
o, assumindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `libpython2.6' faltando
, assumindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `libusb-0.1-4' faltando
, assumindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `libpci3' faltando, ass
umindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `libxml-sax-perl' falta
ndo, assumindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `libpam0g' faltando, as
sumindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `libpopt0' faltando, as
sumindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `ncurses-base' faltando
, assumindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `python-zope.interface'
 faltando, assumindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `linux-image-generic-pa
e' faltando, assumindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `libfuse2' faltando, as
sumindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `python-minimal' faltan
do, assumindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `libgssapi-krb5-2' falt
ando, assumindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `dnsutils' faltando, as
sumindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `libgeoip1' faltando, a
ssumindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `wpasupplicant' faltand
o, assumindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `procps' faltando, assu
mindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `cpp-4.4' faltando, ass
umindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `libparted0debian1' fal
tando, assumindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `libcurl3-gnutls' falta
ndo, assumindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `lsb-base' faltando, as
sumindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `libtasn1-3' faltando,
assumindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `libuuid1' faltando, as
sumindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `lzma' faltando, assumi
ndo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `python-dbus' faltando,
 assumindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `libjs-jquery' faltando
, assumindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `libbind9-60' faltando,
 assumindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `libgcrypt11' faltando,
 assumindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `libgdbm3' faltando, as
sumindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `libhtml-format-perl' f
altando, assumindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `man-db' faltando, assu
mindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `libffi5' faltando, ass
umindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `module-init-tools' fal
tando, assumindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `gettext-base' faltando
, assumindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `libdbus-1-3' faltando,
 assumindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `libgmp3c2' faltando, a
ssumindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `ubuntu-serverguide' fa
ltando, assumindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `gpgv' faltando, assumi
ndo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `login' faltando, assum
indo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `telnet' faltando, assu
mindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `libxml2' faltando, ass
umindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `wireless-crda' faltand
o, assumindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `laptop-detect' faltand
o, assumindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `makedev' faltando, ass
umindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `initramfs-tools' falta
ndo, assumindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `python-twisted-bin' fa
ltando, assumindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `libxmuu1' faltando, as
sumindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.
(Lendo banco de dados ... 35%
dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `libisccfg60' faltando,
 assumindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `libclass-accessor-perl
' faltando, assumindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `libxml-parser-perl' fa
ltando, assumindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `debianutils' faltando,
 assumindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `libfreetype6' faltando
, assumindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `sudo' faltando, assumi
ndo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `coreutils' faltando, a
ssumindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `libxdmcp6' faltando, a
ssumindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `libmpfr1ldbl' faltando
, assumindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `dash' faltando, assumi
ndo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `memtest86+' faltando,
assumindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `libelf1' faltando, ass
umindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `debconf' faltando, ass
umindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `libtext-wrapi18n-perl'
 faltando, assumindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `tcpd' faltando, assumi
ndo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `python-pkg-resources'
faltando, assumindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.

dpkg: aviso: Arquivos da lista de arquivos para o pacote `libxml-libxml-perl' fa
ltando, assumindo que o pacote não possui arquivos atualmente instalados.
(Lendo banco de dados ... 57 arquivos e diretórios atualmente instalados).
Preparando para substituir php5-common 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.24 (usando .../php5-common
_5.3.2-1ubuntu4.26_i386.deb) ...
Desempacotando substituto php5-common ...
dpkg: erro processando /var/cache/apt/archives/php5-common_5.3.2-1ubuntu4.26_i38
6.deb (--unpack):
 impossível criar '/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime.dpkg-new' (enquanto processava './u
sr/lib/php5/maxlifetime'): Permissão negada
dpkg-deb: sub-processo colar foi morto por sinal (Pipe quebrado)
Erros foram encontrados durante o processamento de:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/php5-common_5.3.2-1ubuntu4.26_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@SAMP:~#
```

---

```
root@SAMP:/var/www/map# sudo apt-get autoremove
Lendo listas de pacotes... Pronto
Construindo árvore de dependências
Lendo informação de estado... Pronto
Você pode querer executar 'apt-get -f install' para corrigí-los.
Os pacotes a seguir têm dependências desencontradas:
  libapache2-mod-php5: Depende: php5-common (= 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.26) mas 5.3.2-1ubu
ntu4.24 está instalado
E: Dependências desencontradas. Tente usar -f.
root@SAMP:/var/www/map# sudo apt-get purge
Lendo listas de pacotes... Pronto
Construindo árvore de dependências
Lendo informação de estado... Pronto
Você pode querer executar 'apt-get -f install' para corrigí-los.
Os pacotes a seguir têm dependências desencontradas:
  libapache2-mod-php5: Depende: php5-common (= 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.26) mas 5.3.2-1ubu
ntu4.24 está instalado
E: Dependências desencontradas. Tente usar -f.
root@SAMP:/var/www/map# sudo apt-get clean
root@SAMP:/var/www/map# apt-get install -f
...
```

don't fix... :/

Comment: And that's why you should always run linux in English!

Answer (score 0):

Run all the following commands in  a terminal

```
sudo apt-get -f install

sudo apt-get autoremove

sudo apt-get purge

sudo apt-get clean
```

Then try to install something

Comment: don't work... other solution? i want cancell the dependences...
`code`
Você deve querer executar 'apt-get -f install' para corrigí-los:
Os pacotes a seguir têm dependências desencontradas:
  libapache2-mod-php5: Depende: php5-common (= 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.26) mas 5.3.2-1ubu
ntu4.24 está para ser instalado
  php5-gd: Depende: php5-common (= 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.26) mas 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.24 está
 para ser instalado
E: Dependências desencontradas. Tente 'apt-get -f install' sem nenhum pacote (ou
 especifique uma solução).`code`

Comment: Please check the link provided by jokerino, it seem like viable solution http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies

Comment: Also, for these English commands to work you may need to use the English system language